# Git: How to show all urls added on a remote

Tags: git

Context: I have the `origin` remote with a the default url after cloning a repo. Because of some Bitbucket updates it was suggested that our team would centralize the repositories by creating another account with one App password for all the projects that the team handles.

At first, I've decided to add another remote using:

```
git remote add norigin <new url>
```

But pushing to two remotes every time would prove to be a hassle.
My search for an one push command solution brought me [here](https://jigarius.com/blog/multiple-git-remote-repositories#two-minute-version).

Basically you can edit/add another url to an existing remote, thus I entered:

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@bitbucket.com:username/repo2
```

Tested if the now `git push origin <some branch>` command would push to both remote urls. The `git log` would then show that `norigin` would be behind by a single commit than the `origin`, but I thought it's because it's treated still as a another individual remote, then checked each individual repo and it was indeed pushing to both repos, thus I deleted the `norigin` remote.

All's good but when I enter `git remote -v` it would only show:

```
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo2 (push)
```

When the expected output should be:

```
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo2 (push)
```

**The Question:** as the title says and the expected output shown, how do you show all the urls added on a specific remote?

What I've tried:

```
git remote -v show origin
git remote get-url --push origin
git remote get-url --all origin
```

but all of them return a single url, and it's either the old or the new url.

Comment: Have you tried just simpler command `git remote show origin` ?

Comment: Yes, it would show 1 fetch URL and 1 push URL.

Answer (score 1):

It might depend on the version of Git used.

I just tested your command with a Git 2.35.1, and the `git remote -v` works as expected:

```
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo1  (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo1  (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo2 (push)
```

Check if the .git/config includes

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@bitbucket.com:username/repo1
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
        pushurl = git@bitbucket.com:username/repo1
        pushurl = git@bitbucket.com:username/repo2
```

Comment: Do you mean the `.gitconfig` file? I can't seem to find a `.git` directory either in the local Git folder or the User's folder. Only objects in the `.gitconfig` file are the `[user]` and `[credential]`.

Comment: I've tried updating my git to latest/2.35.1 deleted all (push) urls, then added only the new url and it was the same.

Comment: Maybe one would need to do a clean install instead of just updating git.

Comment: @Yong Sorry I did not answer immediately (it was nighttime for me). I did mean the `.git/config` file, with `.git` being the subfolder under your repository root folder. That is the local configuration.

Comment: No worries! Thank you for answering, I did find the `config` file and as expected there are only 3 urls in the `[remote "origin"]`. `url = git@bitbucket.com:username/repo1`, `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`, and `pushurl = git@bitbucket.com:username/repo2`.

Comment: It's also weird because when I delete all (push) urls, there would be only two left on the `config` file's `[remote "origin"]`, the `url = git@bitbucket.com:username/repo1` and `fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`. But `git remote -v` would also show the automatically added (push) url which is the same as the (fetch) url.

Comment: @Yong Then do a `git config -l --show-scope --show-origin` to see if the additional push URL would come from another config file.

Comment: The result shows that the additional pushurl also comes from `local` just like the url and fetch.

Answer (score 1):

### **To get the expected output:**

```
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo  (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo  (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo2  (push)
```

All I had to do was to also add the original repo url just like how I added the 2nd one. Used this same command but with the original url (not really a solution as there wasn't really a problem in the beginning, but if you nitpick like me and you just want to see a `push` url for the old/original remote then you can use the below command to add it):

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@bitbucket.com:username/repo
```

### **How I arrived to the "workaround?":**

After rereading [this](https://jigarius.com/blog/multiple-git-remote-repositories#two-minute-version) I noticed that the instruction was to add the original repo url when it was added after `git remote add`. You can see the instruction below (the example use .org and .com urls):

```
# Create a new remote called "all" with the URL of the primary repo.
git remote add all git@github.com:jigarius/toggl2redmine.git
# Re-register the remote as a push URL.
git remote set-url --add --push all git@github.com:jigarius/toggl2redmine.git
# Add a push URL to a remote. This means that "git push" will also push to this git URL.
git remote set-url --add --push all git@bitbucket.org:jigarius/toggl2redmine.git
```

Another experiment I did yesterday was to delete all `push` urls that was added in the `origin` repo, and the result was what gave light to this issue.

```
C:~\app> git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo2 (push)

C:~\app> git remote set-url --delete --push origin git@bitbucket.com:username/repo2

C:~\app> git remote -v
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.com:username/repo (push)
```

After deleting all `push` urls, it added a default url the same as the `fetch` url automatically. I don't know the exact behavior, but I just interpreted this as git making the original/old url to be the default `push` url that's why it doesn't have to be shown? Anyway feel free to add to any of this. Also having it shown or not, it would still work as expected as long as you added the new repo (i.e. it will be pushing to both the old and new repo).

PS: As @VonC said in his answer this might differ between different git versions.